# "Error: Could not find or load main class" when trying to launch Run Configuration in Intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

In a project that was originally set up for python I *do* have both python and java SDK's defined:

[image]

I am attempting to run a `scala` program: and the `src` directory is correctly marked as `sources`:

[image]

The class itself does have a `main` :

[image]

But the Intellij does not provide assist for setting up a `Run Configuration` - which should have been available by right click/context menu.  So I set it up manually:

[image]

But when trying to actually run the program it is not successful saying `Error: Could not find or load main class com.blazedb.algos.CourseraAlgos`:

[image]

**Update**: for reference purposes here is a `Run Configuration` from a similar project that *does* work.  I do not see any structural differences between the two.

[image]
Any ideas why Intellij does not recognize the file as a scala class?

Comment: Seems like your package is named "src", not "uni"?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I do not understand your comment - pls clarify.

Comment: The "use classpath of module" in your last image points to "uni". But from your image, it seems that your class is defined inside a package called "src".

Comment: I have used the standard `maven` / `sbt` packaging structure.  To help out here I added a screenshot of a similar but working `Run Configuration`: the structures are analogous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the steps shown above I had also tried:

- adding a new scala-specific module
- nuking and recreating the IJ project

These did not resolve the issue. It turns out the problem is that there were ***no `pom.xml`*** in this project. The resulting behavior by Intellij made it difficult to trace down the root cause: there was no message like

> You need a `pom.xml` or a `build.sbt` to proceed

Apparently stray `scala` classes (dissociated from a formal build) are only haphazardly supported in Intellij.

So finally the answer is to *create a new scala based project*. Adding scala back to a project built for python is at the least unreliable and maybe not possible at all.